# Kernel of a (not so) simple $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/n]$ map

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I'm stuck on a quick algebra problem. Say I have a cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n = \{1, a, ..., a^{n-1}\}$ (written multiplicatively), and form the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{Z}/n]$, and have some module $M$ over it.

I am trying to find the kernel of the map $f : M \longrightarrow M : x \mapsto (1 + a + \dots + a^{n-1})\cdot x$.

It is pretty straightforward that $\ker(f)$ will contain all the elements $x$ that can be written $(1 - a) y$ for some $y \in M$, but I don't know whether this describes the **whole** kernel - and if that is the case, I don't see how to prove it.

Any hints will be mostly appreciated, thanks! :)

---

*Edit: I am actually pretty sure the kernel is bigger than what I originally thought. Surely it should contain all elements of the form $(g^i - g^j)x$ for $i,j$ integers. I am now trying to prove that this is enough.*

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my notation!

Comment: Perhaps it may be helpful to quotient out by this submodule you define ($(1-a)M$), and apply the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: The quotient of this kernel by the elements $(1-a)M$ that are obviously contained in it is precisely the first (or any odd degree, actually) cohomology group $H^1(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},M)$. I see no reason for this to have an any more obvious description for arbitrary $M$ than what we already have.

Comment: @Thorgott I was indeed starting to feel like that I was missing something, thank you for your answer :)